# How to calculate correct height of the table in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, html-table, vue-component, element-ui

I have a table element from element-ui:

```html
 <el-table ref="table" :height="tableHeight"> </el-table>
```

And this is how I am trying to calculate the height:

```js
calculateTableHeight() {
      if (!this.$refs.table) {
        return;
      }

      const tableElement = this.$refs.table.$el;
      const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
      const tableOffsetTop = tableElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const bottomPadding = 30;

      this.tableHeight = viewportHeight - tableOffsetTop - bottomPadding;

      if (tableOffsetTop > viewportHeight / 2) {
        this.tableHeight = viewportHeight / 2;
      }
    },
```

So I am getting the table element, and I am calculating the height of the view. So each row has a checkbox, and as soon as one of them is selected, the element shows `1 element selected` for example. But whenever I click the last item's checkbox in the table, the scroll goes wrong and goes to the top a little bit. So I want to fix this and maybe calculate the height differently. Open any suggestions...

Comment: Have you tried `$el.clientHeight` ?

Comment: where should I try it?

Comment: try : `console.log(this.$refs.table.clientHeight)`

Comment: But instead of what I should use it? Scroll still acts weird

Comment: are you getting the height of the table?

Comment: yes I am getting the height

Comment: I think you have to set a fix height of your table `div`. Can you create an example in stackblitz or anywhere?

Comment: I think there is insufficient informations about this behavior, maybe a gif would show what happens. This calculation is made only while component is mounted or every time this checkboxes are toggled? 

From what you wrote, considering `the scroll goes wrong and goes to top a little bit` I might think that page is scrollable and height is recalculated each checkbox toggle. And that would cause table height to change on certain conditions (in your implementation).

Comment: Yes thats exactly what it is.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` returns element position in viewport, top position is from top of the screen, not document. So when you scroll and recalculate, this will eventually make offset `> viewportHeight / 2` so it's height is halved.

Comment: The naive approach to solve issue above would be to add `document.body.scrollTop` to `tableOffsetTop`, but document might not be the actual scrollable parent of the table, best way would be to find it, and measure scrollTop of that element.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? What is the objective here, are you trying to make the table half the height as the entire screen?

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption here that you are using [Element+](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html#table-with-status) ?

Are you trying to set the height of an element+ table to be 50% of the available viewport height? there is no explanation of your end goal...

On assumption, you should be able to simply set a view height of 50:

```js
<el-table height="50vh" style="width: 100%">
```

vh = Viewport height

Comment: fixed height cannot solve my problem because tableHeight needs to change when one of the checkmark is marked. thats why I calculate the height

Comment: I need to understand the problem in order to help, I don't understand why you need to calculate the height in the first place, to achieve what exactly? There may be a totally different solution available for whatever the underlaying problem is your trying to solve.

Comment: So in my table, each row includes checkbox. As soon as one of them is selected, there is a box opening at the top of the table like '1 is selected'. Because of this, tableHeight needs to be calculated because opened box has also height. So I want my table as same height even after the box opened

Comment: And I am using element-ui https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US